# How can I love gooooooold?

Tags: achievements, crypt-of-the-necrodancer

I kinda like gold, but I don't know if I can *love* gold. This is one of the new Crypt of the Necrodancer achievements:

> **I love gooooooold!**
>
> Have 6000 coins in a single run

Is there a roughly general strategy you can use to get this achievement?

- Should I go for a golden longsword in health shops and a ring of war or a regular weapon and a gold ring?
- Do I want a shrine of war for more enemies or a shrine of rhythm for a bigger multiplier?
- Are there other gold-affecting items I should be aware of?

Comment: [My best run so far at 4,564¢](http://i.imgur.com/QD7lJe0.png), ranking 215th in Bard's leaderboard. I acquired the armor almost immediately, the golden broadsword in 1-2 (health shop), the ring of war in 2-1 and the handy heal spell along the way. Still no cigar T__T

Answer (score 7):

- Get a **gold weapon** (preferably the longsword) from one of a blood shop (they're pretty common in 1-1). According to the wiki, what they do is [drop 1-3 extra coins per monster](http://crypt-of-the-necrodancer.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons), although I had the feeling that they would increase gold drops by significantly more than that. The gold longsword does costs 1.5 hearts to buy (leaving you with half), but it's a perfectly reasonable and reliable weapon to win the game with.
- The **ring of war** increases your damage, your knockback *and* the amount of enemies spawned in future floors. More enemies means more gold.
- The **ring of shadows** lets you get items from all shops for free. That can be very helpful early on.
- The **crown of greed** doubles all gold pickups, but you lose 1¢ per turn. You can get it by killing the shopkeeper, which is easier said than done. As a side effect, this kills the shopkeeper on *all* floors, which means shops will be empty.
- **Ballet shoes** mean you will only lose your coin multiplier when you take damage.
- If you can find a **green scroll** of need and you have *precisely* 0¢, you'll get 500 for free.
- The **yellow scroll** is easier to take advantage of: use it when your coin multiplier is 3 to get 150¢.
- If you have an **obsidian shovel**, get a coin multiplier of 3 and use a **purple scroll** in the neighbourhood of a shop. While gigantism persists, you can dig down gold walls for 10¢ apiece.
- Even just a regular pickaxe, however, leaves you with lots of **leftover bombs**. Use bombs on the inner corners of shops for 50¢ a pop. That makes transmogrifying your basic shovel easily worth the price.
- The **shrine of war** makes all enemies in future floors into their hardest variants (e.g. all skeletons will be black and all bats red). Harder enemies means more gold (but those black riding skeletons are quite annoying to deal with).
- **Arena runes** (the black ones) give you two more minibosses to defeat, with the associated gold.
- Wait for **zone 4** to be released. So far it seems like you really *have* to get the crown of greed to get above 6,000¢ by the end of zone 3. When Zone 4 will be released, you can probably reach that milestone by simply using a gold weapon, killing all enemies and a ring of war.

Comment: "Using the Scroll of Need with zero coins now gives you a COUPON item instead of coins", as for the [v0.394 build](http://braceyourselfgames.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=1689)

Answer (score 3):

Play in hardcore mode, so you'll have nine normal floors and three boss chambers.

On the first two floors, get a gold ring, a gold weapon that you'll be comfortable using for the rest of the run, and two bombs.

Kill the shopkeeper with those bombs and a final strike, and take his crown.

Run through to the end with as few wasted moves as possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are two key and extremely valuable tools in easily obtaining this achievement:

- [The Crown of Greed](http://crypt-of-the-necrodancer.wikia.com/wiki/Headwear): This doubles all coin pickups, but drains 1 gold per beat.
- [The Blood Shovel](http://crypt-of-the-necrodancer.wikia.com/wiki/Equipment): This allows you to dig a chunk of shop walls at the cost of 1/2 heart.

Use any extra bombs and the blood shovel on shop walls (including portal shop walls). Using a blood weapon and a healing spell can keep your health in a comfortable range, and a potion can top off your health to dig more shop walls.

Watching replays of players who complete the daily challenge can provide valuable insight on how to get 6000+ gold. Frequently top-scorers achieve 15,000+ gold on any given day.