# Do gold weapons and the Ring of Gold stack?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

All guides based around high money/score mention gold weapons and the Ring of Gold, including the answers to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/190176/how-can-i-love-gooooooold).

However, there are differing opinions on whether it's worth getting both. Some guides even imply it doesn't add any extra gold (and causes weirdness with the gold weapon's damage).

Do the effects of these items stack, giving me more gold than just having one of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this hasn't got any answer, I'll supply with the generic [wiki search](http://crypt-of-the-necrodancer.wikia.com/wiki/Equipment)

What it says about gold weapons :

> Monsters drop **1 additional base gold** (is affected by the the Groove Chain multiplier). Makes monsters in boss fights drop 1 gold. Deals 999 damage on the beat after collecting any amount of gold.

What it says about the golden ring :

> Killed enemies drop **1 additional gold** (is *not* affected by the Groove Chain multiplier).

If you are lucky enough to find the ring of becoming and transmute it (transmogrifier NPC or transmute spell/scroll), you can have access to the most valuable ring of the game, **the ring of Wonder**

Here is one of the bonuses attributed to the player wearing this ring :

> Killed enemies drop **2 additional gold** (is not affected by the Groove Chain multiplier).

The two pieces of equipment stack up the gold, and having only the gold weapon is better than having only the gold ring, due to a groove multiplier influence.

---

`GM` = groove multiplier
`BD` = Base drop of the ennemy

drops :
no gold equipement : `GM` * `BD`
gold ring : `GM` * `BD` + 1
gold weapon : `GM` * (`BD` + 1 )
both : `GM` * (`BD` + 1 ) + 1

EXAMPLES :

Green slime, x4, both pieces
4 * (1+1) + 1 = 9

Green dragon, x3, both pieces
3 * (10 + 1) + 1 = 34

EXCEPTION : With both pieces of equipement, the boss minions (any mob inside the boss room except the boss) only drop 1 coin due to the gold weapon's attribute. Having the ring won't make them drop a coin.
Also, in the case of death metal's summons, the number of 1-coin drops have a limit.

Comment: I'm still not clear about killing the shopkeeper with a gold weapon (does it drops gold under the crown of greed?), or mobs with 0 `BD` with only the ring. More testing will ensue.